# Function parameter receiving an empty string when I pass an ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got a weird behavior in my `ng-click`.

When I click in the "Done" button, I call my `someAction` function passing an ID.

When I inspect the element in Chrome, it show me `someAction(134)` like should be.

But in my someAction function, the actionId parameter it's always an empty string and I don't figure it out yet.

Someone could help me to solve this ?

**JS**

```
function DetalheAcaoCtrl($scope, $http, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {        
    $scope.someAction = function (actionId) {
        $scope.showPopup(actionId);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
  <div class="row row-footer row-center">
    <div class="col col-footer text-right">
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="someAction({{item.Id}})">Done</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

**Chrome**

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
  <div class="row row-footer row-center">
    <div class="col col-footer text-right">
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="someAction(134)">Done</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do the curly braces when working within (ng click in this case) angular.

```
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="someAction(item.Id)">Done</button>
```

The reason it renders correctly in chrome is because it'll just have the dom ready, but angular won't of wired up the number you need. It's trying to pass in the variable `134`, not the value. So the variable `134` is undefined on that scope.